# Can I use the $( ... ) syntax with multiline commands?

Tags: bash, shell, jq, command-substitution

I often use backticks in with long commands that I break up with backslash-newlines for readability. When I replace the backticks with the `$( ... )` syntax, I get errors.

For instance, I set a variable using `curl` and `jq` inside backquotes (reading from my Trello daily to-do list and returning card.id and card.name for everything but a specific card):

```
AllCardsInDTL=\
`\
curl -s "https://api.trello.com/1/lists/$DailyTasksListID/cards\
?$WhoMe\
&fields=name,id,pos\
"\
| jq  '\
    .[] | \
    if .name | test ("Tasks here are copied.*") \
    then empty \
    else .id, .name \
    end \
    '\
`  # End of AllCardsInDTL=
```

That has no problems and the shell variable consists of alternating lines of ID and Name values.

But if I replace the backquoteswith `$( ... )`, I get an error from `jq`:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
\
jq: 1 compile error
(23) Failed writing body
```

It's not clear to me from the error, whether the `)` is not actually terminating the command started by `$(` or whether inside the `$( ... )` the backslash is not being interpreted as I expect.

I would like to be able to use the `$( ... )` syntax because there are times when I want to nest one subshell inside another and that's very difficult to do with backquotes.

Comment: Please show the code where the backticks are replaced with `$(...)`, or at least the two lines of code in question.

Answer (score 7):

You can certainly use `\` to escape end-of-lines inside a `$(...)` expression. Also note that you **don't** need those `\`'s in the `jq` expression inside the single quotes.

I would probably write it something like this:

```
AllCardsInDTL=$(
curl -s "https://api.trello.com/1/lists/$DailyTasksListID/cards\
?$WhoMe\
&fields=name,id,pos" |
jq  '.[] |
    if .name | test ("Tasks here are copied.*")
    then empty
    else .id, .name
    end
    '
)
```

I can't test this, since I don't have a useful value for `$DailyTasksListID` nor am I equipped to authenticate to trello at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about not needing the backslashes inside the jq singlequotes.

I notice the pipe at the end of the line between the curl and jq does not have a backslash in your version. Is that generally allowable in bash scripts or is only inside the $(...) here?

Comment: That's generally allowable in bash scripts.

Comment: I really like breaking up long command lines to be able to more easily read the flow so this tip will save me a LOT of backslashes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Demo:

```
echo $(echo foo
echo bar
echo baz
)
```

Output:

```
foo bar baz
```

Comment: Ah! the internal three echo commands will put one word per line but that is then sent to echo again which puts them all on one line. I think I'm catching on. Thanks.

Comment: ...and note that if you put quotes (`"`) around the `$(...)` expression, it will then preserve newlines.